# Реализация проставления оценки на модель

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пользователь будет ставить оценку на историю. Как это можно реализовать, направить его на StoryView(ModelViewSet) или есть легкий способ для проставления оценки пользователем?

```
class Story(models.Model):
...
    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.rating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rate'))['rate__avg']

class Rating(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
             CheckConstraint(check=Q(rate__range=(0, 10)), name='valid_rate'),
             UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'story'], name='rating_once')
    ]
```

urls.py

```
router.register('rate', StoryView, basename='rate')
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используешь `ModelViewSet`, то создай метод для `StoryView`, например `add_rating`, что-то типа

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response



class StoreView(ViewSet, ...):

    ...
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    add_rating(self, request, pk=None):
        store = self.get_object()
        user = self.requesr.user
        serializer = CreateRatingSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            Rating.objects.create(user=user, store=store, rating=serializer.data['rating']))
            return Response(...)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Это очень условный пример одной из возможных реализаций.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь в моделе Story создать филд оценка и применить параметр choice:

```
story_rating = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STORY_RATES, default=1)

CLIENT_STATE = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
    ('4', '4'),
    ('5', '5')
)
```